# Terraform dynamically reference data objects

Tags: terraform

I am reaching out to see if anyone has come across the need to try and do the following in Terraform.

```
data.aws_iam_policy_document.${var}.json
```

Basically creating a bunch of IAM policy documents with data. After which, I want to loop over a module call with for_each and use the key to reference the data object and send the json property of the said object as a var to the module.

Psuedo code:

```
module "example" {
  source = "../example"
  for_each = var.default_endpoints
  policy = lookup(lookup(data.aws_iam_policy_document, var.default_endpoints[each.key].name), "json", null)
}
```

Comment: To answer your first question, the path of far less resistance (and far greater robustness) would be to utilize the `templatefile` function for the `policy` argument in the resource. To answer the second question, the path of less resistance would be to input the list of documents/endpoints and iterate over those within the module.

Comment: @MattSchuchard Thanks. `templatefile` would allow for the path to be a constructed string - that will help. Your answer doesn't "literally" answer my question though. Key point being, are you able to data.aws_iam_policy_document.${var}.json or not? It would appear not.